# The ordering of indexes group

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I read somewhere there is a different between these two indexes groups:

- `ADD KEY id_user (id_user,seen);`
- `ADD KEY id_user (seen,id_user);`

Well is there? If yes so their order should be based on what parameter?

---

In reality I have these two queries on one table:

**Query1:**

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id_user = :id AND seen IS NULL
```

**Query2:**

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id_user = :id AND timestamp > :tm
```

So what kind of indexes would be proper in my case? Currently I have three separated indexed on `id_user`, `seen`, `timestamp` columns.

Comment: Think about it; if the data is ordered by `seen` then by `user_id`, how do you *quickly* find all the records for `user_id = 1`?  Even if there are only 3 values for `seen` {0, 1, NULL}, you have to search 3 times.  First got to the `seen = 0` section and then lookup your user, then again for `seen = 1` and again for `seen IS NULL`...  But if your data is ordered by `user_id` then by `seen`?  You only search for your user once.

Comment: A longer discussion in my [_indexing cookbook_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your queries have an equality condition on `id_user`.  Hence, either can take advantage of an index where `id_user` is the first key in the index.  So, I would recommend the first index you mention.

MySQL has good documentation on multi-column indexes.  I would suggest you start [there](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) to learn about them.

Your query can take advantage of indexes on `(id_user, seen)` and `(id_user, timestamp)`.  Probably, the first key is most important.  You should try this different indexes and see which best meet your performance goals.

Comment: Thank you .. upvote. And ok I'll take a look at documentation you linked. Just what do you mean "*the first index you mention*"? This `ADD KEY id_user (id_user,seen);`? in this there isn't any index for `timestamp` column.

Comment: @Stack . . . `ADD KEY` is one way of creating an index.

Comment: All I want to know is, should I use separated indexes on those three columns or one group? If group, it should be containing what columns and what order?

Comment: Well I got it now .. my last question *(just to be sure)*: One of these `(id_user, seen)` and `(id_user, timestamp)` is enough or both of them?

Comment: @Stack . . . Each index is optimized for one of the queries.  However, because `id_user` is the first key in both, either query can make use of the index -- just not optimally.

Comment: Honestly I'm embarrassed to ping you again. But look, I don't know English very well, so please just tell me in one word: should I use `(id_user, seen)` and `(id_user, timestamp)` ? or just `(id_user, seen)` ?

Comment: @Stack . . . You can use both indexes if you want the most optimal indexes for both queries.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, an index on `user_id` is enough. But if you have many repetitions of `user_id`s, then you can make two index groups

```
ADD KEY id_user1 (id_user, seen);
ADD KEY id_user2 (id_user, timestamp);
```

The select will first use `user_id` to reduce the number or matches, then the second field in the index, either `timestamp` or `seen`.

For a select that looks for `user_id` and `seen`, these two indexes

```
ADD KEY id_user1 (id_user,seen);
ADD KEY id_user2 (seen,id_user);
```

will have mostly the same result.

In any case, you should use `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM ...` to check the execution of slow queries, so you can see exactly where it is slow, and if your indexes are actually used as expected.

Comment: Thanks your your explanations .. +1